# Copy-item in foreach loop based off metadata

Tags: windows, powershell, foreach, scripting, copy-item

In this script I identify the metadata for a group of pictures, then run an `if` statement inside a `foreach` loop to copy all pictures from one folder with a certain date to a new directory with that date.

My problem is with `Copy-Item`, or so I think. If I use the variable `$file$` it just places another directory inside the previous directory. The way I have it no just copies all the pictures into that directory despite the `if` statement that it is contained in.

```
$fol = "C:"

foreach ($file in $fol) {

    $data1 = Get-FileMetaData "C:"
    $data2 = $data1 | Select-Object 'Date taken'

    if ($data2 -like '*2006*') {

        if(!(Test-Path "C:\2006")) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\2006"
        }

        Copy-Item  "C:\*" "C:\2006"         
        echo $data2
    } else {
        echo 'no'
    }
}
```

`echo $data2` displays:

[image: return]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why use metatdata for found creation date. You can use creationtime

try this

```
#if you want move for specific year
$destination="c:\destination\2016"
New-Item -ItemType Directory $destination -Force
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\" -Recurse -File -Filter "*.png" | Where {$_.CreationTime.Year -eq 2016} | %{Copy-Item $_.FullName "$destination\$($_.Name)" }

#if you want copy all image png by year of creation
$destination="c:\destination"

Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\" -Recurse -File -Filter "*.png" | group {$_.CreationTime.Year} | 
%{
$DirYear="$destination\$($_.Name)"
New-Item -ItemType Directory $DirYear -Force
$_.Group | %{Copy-Item $_.FullName "$DirYear\$($_.Name)" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
#explicite version
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\" -Recurse -File -Filter "*.png" |
    ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName (New-Item -ItemType Directory "$destination\$($_.CreationTime.Year)" -Force).FullName}

#short version
gci "c:\temp\" -R -File -Fi "*.png" |
    % {cpi $_.FullName (ni -I Directory "$destination\$($_.CreationTime.Year)" -Force).FullName}
```